# Search in metadata on internet

Tags: metadata

my Canon EOS was stolen and I know serial number.
Is it some way how to search metadata serial in google because it is possible that person upload pictures from my Canon on fcb/net 
Thank you

Comment: Presuming fcb is facebook, facebook strips all meta data I'm afraid, and that's before you deal with public/private content.

Comment: [Why is Google a requirement?](https://www.bing.com/search?q=find+stolen+camera+by+serial+number&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=undefined&sc=0-35&sk=&cvid=7B9C75C4DA1E4C9A858D37B466A1F20E) Plenty of other people have done this already.

Comment: Why do people think the police don't know these things ?

Answer (score 4):

What you are probably look for is the [Stolen Camera Finder](http://www.stolencamerafinder.com/home?searchType=manual). Given it your serial number (or a sample photo) and it will look for it among publicly accessible images (presumably not all of them) but this is intended exactly for people who upload images to social platforms and online galleries.

Comment: Stolen camera finder doesnt do anything anymore due to their program has been stripped- I had my camera stolen aswell and am trying to come up with something to trace pictures taken with it- i can come back if i find a solution -